# How to read string input which may contain quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a text input where user can input any text. When i set variable value to that input it ends the string if user inputs single quote.

```
var name = $("#recipeName").val();
```

And this is my form

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="recipeName">
```

If user enter "Tom's recipe of potatoes"

```
var name = '"Tom's recipe of potatoes"';
```

Is there a way to read inputs without ending string on first ' ?

Comment: This is not what would happen, don't worry.

Comment: Did you try it and got an error or something?

Comment: You only need to worry about escaping quotes in strings when you hard-code them, or output them to the HTML.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f206c704d9990469bc8fdd998f79ce25

Comment: @ŽilvinasRingelė that's because you're writing it in the source code directly, but if the user put it into an input and you read its value it's not what would happen.

Comment: This is not what you described... you described something completly different from your question. to escape a quote in your js code you add a \ before the character you want to escape

Comment: This is what i get when i test it on localhost and check console. I am sorry if question was not clear

Comment: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p30qqvcf/2/

Comment: Well, that means there is some error where i use that var further, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coding a string with quotes and reading HTML or data that contains quotes are two different things.

In the source code you must escape the quotes because they break the syntax of JavaScript, however, when you just read a string, JavaScript does not care if the character is a letter, number or a quote.

See minimal example below.

```js
console.log($('#foo').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo" value="That's the spirit" />
```